# Use curl in php to login to a website that requieres csrf_token

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login into a site using php curl but I am no familiar with csrf_token which I see in my post data that I am also sending this. Below is my code and I am not able to log in.
The csrf_token my browser sends is:

csrf_token=20131028152953%23%23f31508fbc631e906973451eefe8a88ce1b9270ad&name=name&password=pass

```
$name="name"; 
$password="pass"; 
$url="domain.com/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "name=".$name."&password=".$password; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `csrf_token` can be anything. You have to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `csrf_token` is changing each time, you load the site. You should first load site, where is login form, then parse in DOM `csrf_token`, and then do your curl as its written in your question.